# Problems in implementing Disqus plugin due to jQuery issues

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, disqus

I am working on a blog website at http://d361.azurewebsites.net/Blog. I have used a template for full page flip from http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/11/fullscreen-pageflip-layou which uses javascript and jquery, other than the obvious.

I have 2 problems.

1. I need disqus plugin on every article of the blog. But since the whole website is basically one single webpage, I have not been able to implement it. Further anchor tags are not working.
   Currently the disqus plugin is working in case of the first article only.
2. I am also using social sharing buttons on the site. Again, they share only the mail website link, i.e d361.azurewebsites.net/Blog and not the actual articles. I tried to use anchor tags but it is not working.

Kindly help me out here. As you must have already known, I dnt know much beyond html and css.

Answer (score 0):

Disqus won't work with single-page applications out of the box, you have to use our AJAX protocol to reload the thread with the new information. The process is documented here: http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472107-using-disqus-on-ajax-sites

Whenever the page content is changing, you would call DISQUS.reset like this:

```
DISQUS.reset({
  reload: true,
  config: function () {  
    this.page.identifier = "new_disqus_identifier";  
    this.page.url = "http://example.com/#!new-url";
  }
});
```

Comment: I found this code under jquery.bookblock.js  
 switch (keyCode) {
      case arrow.left:
       self._action('prev');
       break;
      case arrow.right:
       self._action('next');
       break;
     }

And to go navigate between pages, the following code in index.html

<nav>
     <span id="bb-nav-prev">&larr;</span>
     <span id="bb-nav-next">&rarr;</span>
    </nav>


Can u guide me implementing the disqus reset function in this scenario?